# Material Design Lite and dialog-polyfill modal dialogs on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, material-design-lite, polyfills, chrome-ios

I'm using Material Design Lite (http://getmdl.io) along with dialog-polyfill (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill) for the modal dialog boxes.

Everything works great on my desktop browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.), but on iOS (both Chrome and Safari), I can't tap inside the modal dialog boxes.  It just doesn't respond.

I've tried the suggestion  I've seen posted several places to put "cursor: pointer" in the CSS, but either I'm not doing it correctly, or it's not working.

Here's a typical modal dialog from my code:

```
<dialog class="mdl-dialog" id="delete_alias_confirm_dialog"> 
<h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">
    Delete alias 
</h4>
<div class="mdl-dialog__content" id="delete_alias_confirm_dialog_content">
    <p>
        Alias [ALIAS NAME] has been successfully deleted. 
    </p>
    <form action="#">
        <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored" onClick="delete_alias_confirm_dialog.close()" id="delete_alias_confirm_dialog_ok_button">OK</button> 
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</dialog>

<script>
    var delete_alias_confirm_dialog = document.querySelector('#delete_alias_confirm_dialog');

    if (! delete_alias_confirm_dialog.showModal) { 
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(delete_alias_confirm_dialog);
    }

    var delete_alias_curr_name=""
    function show_delete_alias_confirmation(clicked_element) {
        delete_alias_curr_name=((clicked_element.parentNode).parentNode).parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('#alias_name').innerText
        var delete_alias_dialog_delete_button=document.querySelector('#delete_alias_dialog_delete_button');
        var delete_alias_dialog_alias_name=document.querySelector('#delete_alias_dialog_alias_name');
        delete_alias_dialog_alias_name.innerHTML=delete_alias_curr_name
        delete_alias_dialog.showModal();
        delete_alias_dialog_delete_button.blur();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the order in which you load the CSS.

If you are loading `dialog-polyfll.css` before `material.min.css` that might be the source of the problem.

Also check if you don't have a `dialog`  duplicate, this also results on a dialog that can't be closed on IOS.